# Fix timestamp skew in already existing syslog files

Tags: linux, date, unix, awk

I am doing a  post-mortem analysis for a distributed system where some hosts had their clocks skewed and hence timestamps in syslog are off by 3 minutes and 12 seconds.

Is there a command line too that could take a file that has lines like these from STDIN:

```
2016-06-13T23:58:43.324758+00:00 Host1 charon: 14[IKE] sending DPD request
...
```

And then in STDOUT print something like this:

```
2016-06-14T00:01:55.324758+00:00 Host1 charon: 14[IKE] sending DPD request
...
```

There are few multi line messages in the syslog so it would be nice if that tool would be able to deal with that too. The first tool that came into my mind is awk, but it is not obvious on how it could do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{split($1,a,"."); 
        gsub(/:|-|T/," ",a[1]); 
        $1=strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.", mktime(a[1])+12+3*60)a[2]}1' log
```

Comment: Nice time manipulation but that will replace all tabs or other sequences of white space in his log files with single blank chars. Instead of `$1=strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.",mktime(a[1])+12+3*60)a[2]` use `sub(/[^[:space:]]+/,strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.",mktime(a[1])+12+3*60)a[2])` to avoid that happening.